# sql queries slower than expected

Tags: sql, left-join, phpbb

Before I show the query here are the relevant table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE phpbb_posts (
    topic_id mediumint(8) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    poster_id mediumint(8) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    KEY topic_id (topic_id),
    KEY poster_id (poster_id),
);


CREATE TABLE phpbb_topics (
    topic_id mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment
);
```

Here's the query I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT p.topic_id, p.poster_id 
FROM phpbb_topics AS t 
LEFT JOIN phpbb_posts AS p 
   ON p.topic_id = t.topic_id 
      AND p.poster_id <> ... 
WHERE p.poster_id IS NULL;
```

Basically, the query is an attempt to find all topics where the number of times someone other than the target user has posted in is zero. In other words, the topics where the only person who has posted is the target user.

Problem is that query is taking a super long time.  Here's the EXPLAIN for it:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [select_type] => SIMPLE
    [table] => t
    [type] => index
    [possible_keys] =>
    [key] => topic_approved
    [key_len] => 1
    [ref] =>
    [rows] => 146484
    [Extra] => Using index
)
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [select_type] => SIMPLE
    [table] => p
    [type] => ref
    [possible_keys] => topic_id,poster_id,tid_post_time
    [key] => tid_post_time
    [key_len] => 3
    [ref] => db_name.t.topic_id
    [rows] => 1
    [Extra] => Using where; Not exists
)
```

My general assumption when it comes to SQL is that JOINs of any are super fast and can be done in no time at all assuming all relevant columns are primary or foreign keys (which in this case they are).

I tried out a few other queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM phpbb_topics AS t 
    JOIN phpbb_posts AS p 
        ON p.topic_id = t.topic_id;
```

That returns 353340 pretty quickly.

I then do these:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM phpbb_topics AS t 
    JOIN phpbb_posts AS p 
        ON p.topic_id = t.topic_id
            AND p.poster_id <> 77198;

SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM phpbb_topics AS t 
    JOIN phpbb_posts AS p 
        ON p.topic_id = t.topic_id
    WHERE p.poster_id <> 77198;
```

And both of those take quite a while (between 15-30 seconds).  If I change the <> to a = it takes no time at all.

Am I making some incorrect assumptions?  Maybe my DB is just foobar'd?

Comment: You should specify what database and version you are using, by incorporating this as a tag on the question.

Comment: You would expect a not-equal condition in a join to take longer than equality, depending on the contents of your tables. Maybe if you put some indices on the tables, you'll see an improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.topic_id 
FROM phpbb_topics AS t 
JOIN phpbb_posts AS p1
   ON p1.topic_id = t.topic_id
      AND p1.poster_id = $poster_id
LEFT JOIN phpbb_posts AS p2 
   ON p2.topic_id = t.topic_id 
      AND p2.poster_id <> $poster_id
WHERE p2.poster_id IS NULL
```

That made it a ton faster. I'm getting all the posts where the target user has posted with the topic info attached to that and then getting all the people other than the target who've posted.

There'll be lots of duplicates in the p1.poster_id column but since I'm not actually getting that row I figure duplicates in that column don't matter a whole lot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think replacing index on `phpbb_posts(topic_id)` to composite index on 2 fields should improve performance of your query :

```
CREATE TABLE phpbb_posts (
topic_id mediumint(8) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
poster_id mediumint(8) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
--KEY topic_id (topic_id), 
KEY topic_id_poster_id (topic_id,poster_id)
KEY poster_id (poster_id),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your indexes look sufficient to me... could you try this query and let me know how the performance compares to your original?

```
SELECT sub.topic_id
FROM (
    SELECT t.topic_id
    FROM phpbb_topics AS t 
    WHERE
        EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM phpbb_posts p
            WHERE 
                p.topic_id = t.topic_id
                AND p.poster_id = 77198
        )
) sub
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM phpbb_posts p
        WHERE 
            p.topic_id = sub.topic_id
            AND p.poster_id <> 77198
)
```

My thoughts are that by limiting the topics to only those that the poster in question has actually posted in, that the anti-join (implemented in this case with `NOT EXISTS` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`) will have to check much fewer topics for posters other than the one being searched.

Comment: I tried that and it takes a while as well.  When I do "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST" the State for that query is "Sending data".  It's been at that state for a few 100 seconds so far..

Comment: I did not know about EXISTS / NOT EXISTS in MySQL though - learn something new everyday!

Comment: @neubert Can you do an `EXPLAIN` on your original query, and update your question with the results?

Comment: @neubert Also, I just made an adjustment to my query, could you please give this one a try and let me know how it compares?

Comment: Updated my original post. Here's a pastebin with the EXISTS / NOT EXISTS stuff: http://pastebin.com/vDH3Ptgr